# How to extract the distance from a Google Directions JSON file on the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, google-maps-api-3

I am having a really hard time extracting a single value I need from a JSON file I get from a Google Directions request.

After sending the request, I get something like that:

```
{
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 31.831330,
               "lng" : 34.834710
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 31.25299000000001,
               "lng" : 34.653460
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2012 Mapa GISrael",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "85.6 km",
                  "value" : 85613",
               },
```

But the only thing I want is the distance value (routes/legs/distance/value),
does any one know how to extract this value from the JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that doesn't seem like well formatted JSON, there is a trialing " after the value of the distance.

Most JSON frameworks will give you the objects in the most appropriate type. Dictionaries will be converted to NSDictionary and a list will be converted to an NSArray.

To get the route distance in the above JSON you'd parse the JSON into an NSDictionary using one of the many libraries out there, then you'd do something like this:

NSNumber *distance = [[[[[[parsedDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"distance"] objectForKey@"value"];

See if that works.

Comment: I have never used json before and my knowledge and experience with it are very mininal, can you please explain how I can differentiate between JSON lists and dictionaries?

Comment: JSON is an object notation. Anything between { and } is a dictionary. It's made of keys which reference an object (number, string, DICTIONARY or Array, boolean, null).

An Array is an ordered list of objects (see above for object definition). Arrays are anything between [ and ].

So, to differentiate between a list/array and a dictionary, look at what is around them. [] are arrays, {} are dictionaries. For much much more info, go here: http://json.org/

Comment: See TouchJSON for an example of a json parsing library

Comment: Your awesome! It Worked like a charm! I was trying to do that all night long and you solved it in a 2 row solution, thank you so much!